# How to manipulate element in Multi-dimensional list python

Tags: python

Updated. 
I've merged the data into multi-dimensional list as shown

```
[('Medical Services', 2), ('Medical Services', 2), ('Physical Therapy', 5), 
 ('Physical Therapy', 1), ('Chiropractic', 0)]
```

Is it possible to get the result as follows

```
 The average response time for Medical Services is 2 days
```

(note that it should remove duplicates)

```
 The average response time for Physical Therapy is 5 days
```

(note that there are two Physical Therapy but I took the highest number of days from it which is 5)

```
 The average response time for Chiropractic is less than 24 hours
```

(note that if it was 0 days then it should change to "less than 24 hours")

Comment: Short answer : yes.

Comment: would be a good idea if you can show few rows in your **rawdata**

Comment: Added the raw data

Comment: Your question is still unclear as there are several parts to it.  You should break it down into distinct pieces.

Comment: Is it? So sorry, I was new to python and couldn't continue from here

Comment: Why are you dividing `(delta_b - delta_a)` by 2? Why aren't you calculating a proper average for each type of service? BTW, you are much more likely to get help with this question if you post a [mcve] that we can run, accompanied by an explanation of what's wrong with that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***Note:*** This answer was meant to address OP's original question, which has subsequently been revised.]

This may not be precisely what you want with respect to the timedelta, but I believe it's close.

I would recommend that you use Pandas for this problem.  Presuming your csv data is in a file called `data.csv`:

```
import pandas as pd

# load the data into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header = None, names = ['Service', 'Reported Date', 'Completion Date', 'Days'])

# convert date strings to dates
df['Reported Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Reported Date'])
df['Completion Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Completion Date'])

# calculate the timedelta and add it to the 'Days' column
df['Days'] = (df['Completion Date'] - df['Reported Date'])

# convert the timedelta to an int
df['Days'] = df['Days'].dt.days

# print our dataframe
print(df)
print

# convert the timedelta 'Days' to days
new_df = df.groupby([df['Service']]).mean()

# print our new dataframe
print(new_df)
print

for row in new_df.itertuples():
    if row[1] < 1:
        print("The average response time for %s is %s days." % (row[0], row[1]))
    else:
        print("The average response time for %s is less than 24 hours." % (row[0]))
```

Yields the following output:

```
================================================================================
Oct 4, 2017, 9:00:40 AM
untitled text 11
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Service       Reported Date     Completion Date  Days
0  Medical Services 2017-03-08 09:20:00 2017-03-12 14:59:00     4
1  Medical Services 2017-03-08 09:28:00 2017-03-12 14:59:00     4
2  Physical Therapy 2017-03-04 09:34:00 2017-03-14 19:21:00    10
3  Physical Therapy 2017-03-04 09:39:00 2017-03-14 15:00:00    10
4  Medical Services 2017-03-01 09:49:00 2017-03-24 19:21:00    23
5      Chiropractic 2017-03-27 10:41:00 2017-03-27 19:22:00     0
6  Medical Services 2017-03-02 10:46:00 2017-03-04 15:00:00     2
7      Chiropractic 2017-03-27 11:36:00 2017-03-27 12:51:00     0
8  Medical Services 2017-03-02 14:17:00 2017-03-02 19:22:00     0

                  Days
Service               
Chiropractic       0.0
Medical Services   6.6
Physical Therapy  10.0

The average response time for Chiropractic is less than 24 hours.
The average response time for Medical Services is 6.6 days.
The average response time for Physical Therapy is 10.0 days.
```

Pandas is a very powerful tool and makes performing operations like these fairly easy.

**UPDATE**

While you will still need to use an external module for the datetime calculations, here is one that uses datetime only.  This script is verbose so that you can see what's going on, but there are several ways to consolidate many of the steps.

```
import datetime

data = []
services = []

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# construct list 'data' which contains the rows of data as lists
for line in lines:
    item = line.strip().split(',')
    data.append(item)

# construct list 'services' which contains a list of unique services
for item in data:
    if item[0] not in services:
        services.append(item[0])

# create a timedelta for each row, convert it to days and add it to the end of each row
for item in data:
    reported = datetime.datetime.strptime(item[1], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
    delivered = datetime.datetime.strptime(item[2], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
    item.append( (delivered-reported).total_seconds() )

for service in services:
    total_days = 0
    counter = 0

    for row in data:
        if service in row:
            total_days += row[3]
            counter += 1

    average_days = (total_days / counter) / 86400

    if average_days < 1:
        print("The average response time for %s is less than 24 hours." % (service))
    else:
        print("The average response time for %s is %.2f days." % (service, average_days))
```

Output:

```
================================================================================
Oct 4, 2017, 10:07:40 AM
untitled text 11
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The average response time for Medical Services is 6.85 days.
The average response time for Physical Therapy is 10.32 days.
The average response time for Chiropractic is less than 24 hours.
```

Comment: Note that my answer is meant to address the original question.

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciated! But I wanted to learn the way of not using third party module

Comment: Added an example that doesn't use pandas (still needs datetime for timedelta operations).

Comment: Hello, The example without pandas. Couldn't print out decimal points any reason? The type of average_days is float

Comment: I've updated the non-pandas example to a two decimal point float. This required changing the timedelta from days to seconds, dividing the average days (now in seconds) by 86400 (the number of seconds in a day), and changing the output strings to account for floats.  Please consider accepting the answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: If adding a down vote, please consider explaining the reason for it.

Comment: I downvoted because I thought that a) the use of pandas was unneccesary, especially for a Python beginner, and b) I didn't understand why you used timedeltas for simple values that just happen to represent time. I've since looked at the history of the question and see that the timedelta part is more relevant to the original version of the question. I would undo my downvote, but it is locked into place until you edit your answer.

Comment: @L3viathan - appreciate the consideration.  I thought it best to leave the original answer given the original question as you found.  I could've been more clear in my first comment to this thread.  Cheers!

Comment: I suggest putting that comment inside your answer, ideally on top.

Comment: Before you changed from days to seconds, when 3/2 = 1.5 but it gave me 1 when both parameters is a float and it didn't return decimal point which I find it weird.

Anyway Thanks!.

Comment: That was because an integer divided by an integer is an integer.  So 3/2 = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple solution without any external libraries:

```
data = [('Medical Services', 2), ('Medical Services', 2), ('Physical Therapy', 5), ('Physical Therapy', 1), ('Chiropractic', 0)]

from collections import defaultdict
label2days = defaultdict(list)
for label, days in data:
    label2days[label].append(day2)
for label, days in label2days.items():
    average = sum(days) / len(days)
    print("The average response time for {0} is {1}".format(
        label,
        "%.2f" % average if average >= 1 else "less than 24 hours",
    ))
```

Prints:

> The average response time for Chiropractic is less than 24 hours
>   The average response time for Physical Therapy is 3.00 days
>   The average response time for Medical Services is 2.00 days